# How to use EU server in Archeage?

Tags: arche-age

I only see NA servers available to connect to at the startup screen. I don't see any option to select an EU server?

Answer (score 4):

On the top right of the Glyph client, there's a drop down box that most likely says North America, click it and choose Europe. Now, when you press the Play button, you'll log on to the European servers. You can switch freely between them any time if you change your mind.